# диалплан asterisk

Tags: asterisk

```
    [call]
    exten => 459,1,Answer()
    exten => 459,n,Playback(hello

-world)
            exten => 459,n(first),Noop(-- TO ENTER NUMBER PRESS 1 --)
            exten => 459,n,Waitexten(4)
            exten => 459,n,GotoIf($["${EXTEN}" == "459"]?call,459,first)

            exten => 459,n(second),Noop(-- TO ENTER NUMBER PRESS 2 --)
            exten => 459,n,Waitexten(10)

            exten => 459,n(summ),Noop(-- PRESS 3 IF YOU WANT TO SUMM NUMBERS --)
            exten => 459,n,Waitexten(10)

            exten => 1,1,Noop(-- PRESS 1 --)
            exten => 1,n,Read(num1)
            exten => 1,n,GotoIf($["${num1}" == "1"]?call,459,second)

            exten => 2,1,Noop(-- PRESS 2 --)
            exten => 2,2,Read(num2)
            exten => 2,n,GotoIf($["${num1}" != ""] &&  $["${num2}" == "2"]?call,459,summ)

       exten => 3,1,Noop(SUMM is: $[${num1} + ${num2}])
       exten => 3,n,HangUp()
```

Подскажите как определить если 3 раза абонент ничего не нажал,то завершить вызов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ничего не нажато, то обработка переходит в exten => t. Добавьте примерно такую логику:

```
exten => t,1,NoOP(-- Nothing pressed --)
 same => n,ExecIf($[ "${ATTEMPT}" == "" ]?Set(ATTEMPT=1):Set(ATTEMPT=${MATH(${ATTEMPT}+1,int)}))
 same => n,ExecIf($[ ${ATTEMPT} > 2 ]?Hangup:Goto(459,first))
```